# How to rename the graphics window when using turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I would like to provide a specific graphics window title in turtle graphics, similar to how `title KJR` works in `cmd.exe`.

I am currently in the process of creating a game, and would like it to display the name, `KJR`, rather than `turtle graphics`.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: You should be able to do it with the [`screen.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.title) method, where `screen = turtle.Screen()`.

Answer (score 3):

....

Use the [`title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.title) function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
turtle.screen.title("Custom title")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the title("Custom title") function

Comment: This was already offered as the top-voted answer from four years ago. Please don’t repeat existing guidance. Once you have a bit more reputation, you’ll be able to upvote existing answers as a way of validating their usefulness.